# Create javascript array which have the same structure with php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In the sever side i have an array with structure like that:

```
array ('_1489378560544_544' => array (
                                     'customer_group_id' => '0',
                                     'permission_id' => 'disable_products_price',),
       '_1489740032764_764' => array (
                                     'customer_group_id' => '',
                                     'permission_id' => '',),)
```

So now in the client side i want to create an javascript array with the same structure to server side. Is there any possible way to do that?

So after i got all data separately how can i organize my array look like this

```
var arr = [{_1489378560544_544 : [customer_group_id : 0 , permission_id : 'permission_id'] }]
```

Here is my javascript get data function:

```
 $('#category_permission > tbody > tr').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var customer_group_id = $(this).children('td:first').children('select:first').val();
                var permission_id = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select:first').val();
            });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For sure. Its quite simple. But we're not here to code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. show us what you've tried so far and we'll help you find your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :
`var arr = [{_1489378560544_544 : [customer_group_id : 0 , permission_id : 'permission_id'] }]`

Comment: Hi Avihay. Your answer is exactly what i'm looking for. So after i got all data separately how can i organize my array like yours. Here is my get data function.
$('#category_permission > tbody > tr').each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var customer_group_id = $(this).children('td:first').children('select:first').val();
                    var permission_id = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select:first').val();
                });

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to do ?

Comment: My purpose is getting data from a table and then organize it like your answer. Obove is my javascript get data function form a table.

Comment: So define a variable like my example and build him with your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)  to convert your PHP array to a JSON string and use `JSON.parse()` to obtain the equivalent Javascript object. Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

in your php view file

```
jsStr = '<?php echo json_encode($array)?>'

jsObj = JSON.parse(jsStr);

console.log(jsObj.keyname);
```

like that all keys can be accessed to get the value. javascript don't support alphanumerical keys for array.
Answer from @Mistalis should help.

Comment: Hi Ervishalporwal. Mistalis's answer is in reverse order to what I want to do. My purpose is getting data from a table and then organize it in the form like @Avihay's answer

Comment: Do you want to print it like @Aviha's answer?